# Process.Start without creating a child process (port handle inheritance)?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, sockets, process

I have a WCF service in a self hosted application using TCP bindings. If I start an external process "commandLineApp" from the application, that continues even after my application has closed, I run into problems next time the WCF service is started by my application.

WCF says that the address/port is already in use. If I close the external application (that isn't using WCF or any sockets at all) before restarting my application, the WCF service starts just fine.

It looks like that the socket handles from my application is somehow inherited by the new process "commandLineApp", and not released until that process has exited.

How do I prevent the other process from inheriting the handles (or becoming a child process?) from my main application? Currently I'm using Process.Start to launch the other process, using UseShellExecute set to False because I need to set both EnvironmentVarables and RedirectStandardOutput/Error.

I think the child process setup is prevented if I set UseShellExecute = true, but then I don't get all features I need.

Are there any way around this problem? See example code below.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();    
psi.FileName = "commandLineApp.exe";
psi.Arguments = "/someParameter";
psi.EnvironmentVariables.Add("...", "...");
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = psi;
process.Start();
// Monitor if process with PID = process.Id is running
// ...
```

Edit - Additional information:
Doing "netstat -noa" indicates that the port is used with state LISTEN by the previous PID of the main application, but there is no process with that PID anymore. As soon as I close "commandLineApp", the port isn't listed by the netstat command anymore.

WCF services are closed like this before the main application exit:

```
try
{
    serviceHost.Close(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));
}
catch (Exception)
{
    serviceHost.Abort();
}
```

Comment: You redirect standard I/O and then *exit*? I think something is very wrong with your design... Also note that TCP connections can survive a few minutes after they're "closed" if it's not a graceful shutdown on both sides. Are you sure the "parent" actually died? Doesn't it have some threads running? How are you handling the shutdown? You should close all the handles explicitly anyway, so your shutdown doesn't sound very graceful... All in all, you shouldn't rely on process exit cleaning up after you - you should do the cleanup yourself!

Comment: I'll bet this has nothing to do with inherited handles and everything to do with the delay caused by not using [`SO_REUSEADDR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi, I have waited several hours, and I've verified that the main process is terminated. Doing "netstat -noa" indicates that the port is used by the previous PID of the main application, but there is no process with that PID anymore. I do manual cleanup of all WCF services and no threads are left behind when closing. If I don't launch the "commandLineApp" I don't have any problems at all restarting the main application, so it's very related to how that process is started. The redirect of I/O is to get the output the first minute from "commandLineApp", to find startup problems.

Comment: @Dark Falcon - Do you know if SO_REUSEADDR can be used in combination with WCF? WCF typically hides all low level socket options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was wrong in the above comment: SO_REUSEADDR would only apply if the handle had been closed, but it seems like socket handles truly are inherited by child processes and there is no easy way to prevent this. This seems like a very stupid design decision, particularly since some places noted that the handle can't be used in the child if any LSPs are installed.

If you had more control over the call to `WSASocket`, you might be able to pass the `WSA_FLAG_NO_HANDLE_INHERIT` flag, but this is going to be hard to accomplish inside WCF. Here's a couple other options:

Option #1: [Call CreateProcess yourself](http://www.davidmoore.info/blog/2011/06/21/when-system-diagnostics-process-creates-a-process-it-inherits-inheritable-handles-from-the-parent-process/) and pass `FALSE` for `bInheritHandles`.

Option #2: Create a helper process before you set up WCF (or any other sockets). [Communicate with it via named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx). Start the child process from this helper instead of from the main process.

Comment: Many thanks! I've implemented Option#1. The only drawback is that bInheritHandles is required for using RedirectStandardOutput, but I use that one mainly for debugging, so I have a switch to turn bInheritHandles on or off depending on the situation.