# Dispose (or Close) killed process

Tags: c#, async-await, process, dispose, kill-process

Calling `process.Dispose()` or `process.Close()` (no matter which one, 'cos `.Close` is called inside `.Dispose` implementation) after `process.Kill()` sometimes hangs application.

I can't reproduce this bug stable, but sometimes when `WaitForExit` finishes by timeout passed to it, application hangs on `process.Close()` command.

Please suggest me, what the cause of this problem may be?

Note:

- I've seen [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50572800/c-sharp-process-hangs-on-dispose). But there are not answers & upvoted comment says, that the cause of the problem perhaps at details, which are not provided at that question. So I added more details.
- I've also seen a [linked solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10235335/3241228), but I can't use `ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;` 'cos I need to redirect output.

Sorry for verbose code, but I pass it such way, 'cos at similar unanswered question commentators noticed, that not enough details provided (as I noted above)

```
private static async Task<int> RunMethod(string processArguments)
{
    // 1. Prepare ProcessStartInfo

    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

    startInfo.Arguments = processArguments;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    // 2. Create process inside using-block to be disposed

    using (var proc = new Process())
    {
        proc.StartInfo = startInfo;

        // 3. Subscribe output streams handlers

        proc.OutputDataReceived += (sender, outputLine) => { HandleMessage(outputLine); };
        proc.ErrorDataReceived  += (sender, errorLine)  => { HandleMessage(errorLine); };

        // 4. Start process

        if (!proc.Start())
        {
            proc.Close();
            return -1;
        }

        // 5. Start the asynchronous read of the standard output stream.

        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        proc.BeginErrorReadLine();

        // 6. Waiting process to exit with timeout on threadpool to not block UI thread

        // Re#er warns me "captured variable `proc` is disposed in the outer scope". But I think it's Ok, 'cos we're awaiting this task inside using block (in next line)
        var waitingProcessTask = Task.Run(() => proc.WaitForExit(TIMEOUT), _cancelToken);
        bool hasExited = await waitingProcessTask;

        // 7. Stop reading streams

        // Not sure, these 2 CalncelXxxRead methods are needed. But hope it won't hurt at least
        proc.CancelErrorRead();
        proc.CancelOutputRead();

        // 8. If !hasExited (i.e. TIMEOUT is reached) we kill the process

        if (!hasExited)
        {
            Logger.Debug("0. Before Kill()");

            proc.Kill();
            proc.Refresh(); // not sure, it's needed
        }

        // If uncomment next 2 lines, then problem moves here from end of using block
        //proc.Close();
        //Logger.Debug("1. after .Close call");  // <------------------ This log we don't see sometimes
        
        Logger.Debug("2. last inside using-block");
    } // end of using block

    Logger.Debug("3. after using-block");  // <------------------ This log we don't see sometimes (if `.Close` wasn't called before)
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not disposing per se that's the problem, it's the async stream read line functionality that causes race conditions. Read the documentation on `Process`, it has numerous warnings about this -- if you use them it's your responsibility to write correct code or freeze your thread.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out with my issue. The problem was: my process once in a while** spawned child daemon-process, which is ment to work forever. Child process (by design) always inherits redirected output streams if parent streams are redirected.

From the other side, `.Kill()` don't kill child processes - only for which it was kalled. (Until .Net 5.0, where `.Kill(bool)` solves this problem).

So `.Dispose()` or `.Close()` never finish, 'cos waits to release output streams, which are held by infinite child process.

It was very interesting adventure to figure out, what is happening =)

---

**) - that's why reproduce was very unstable

*PS: Thank to @Blindy for directing me the way quite close to where the real cause of problem lie.*